# Routing my URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I tried remapping my URL, but without any success. Here is my URL:

```
localhost:8888/nordia/site/categorie/1/transportwagon
```

What I'm trying to do is remove the "site" part from URL and keep it like:

```
localhost:8888/nordia/categorie/1/transportwagon
```

I tried mapping it like:

```
 $route['site/categorie'] = "categorie";
```

But it is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your categorie method takes two arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`$route['categorie/(:num)/(:any)'] = "site/categorie/$1/$2";`

Comment: You forgot `(:num)/(:any)`

Comment: Thanks, So if i wanted to remove categorie also i should do $route['(:num)/(:any)'] = "site/categorie/$1/$2"; ?

Comment: Yeah, give it a shot.

Comment: It works, Great! Still i have one more question is there a possibilty to overwrite the url after clicking                  <?php echo site_url('categorie/'.$row->cat_id .'/'.$row->naam); ?>       because i want the function to be executed when a button gets clicked but i don't want to show it in the URL, and it seems that i can't get rid of that with a route after clickin the site_url